# passing PHP var to JS var

Tags: javascript, php

I have a small issue. I can't seam to pass a variable from PHP to JS.

Here is my JS:

```
var eName = '<?php echo $eName; ?>';
```

I know that $eName has a value. However in the JS section, I get nothing. no data seams to be present in the variable. when I echo in the PHP section, I get data.

Can anyone help?

Also tried:

```
var eName = '<?php echo json_encode($eName); ?>';
```

This give me a null result

Thanks for your help

Here is how I get my PHP Variable populated:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM league WHERE id='". $lID ."' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($numrows < 1){
        echo "league does not exist";
        exit();
    }
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $eName = $row["name"];
```

Comment: Can you please post your `$eName` echo result in PHP?

Comment: Sounds like a scoping issue in PHP. Are you sure the variable is defined in the global PHP scope?

Comment: Works fine for me! Also should work for you! Please show us more code

Comment: Did you put your PHP code in a .js file?

Comment: $eName is not an array. I get a single name from my database. such as: "VIP", "8 Ball". Not sure I understand the global PHP scope question, I'll read on it.

Comment: Actually, it should be just `var eName = <?php echo json_encode($eName); ?>;`, without any quotes; that's the safest way, unless `$eName` contains non-serializable data. Could you show what's put in the source code as a result?

Comment: You are pushing the PHP code in the JS File. JS cannot interpret the php code. You need to use JS ajax to load the data as a web service ot some other way around

Comment: Raina77ow, I tried it already. The alert returns a NULL value.

Comment: I didn't mention any alert, did I? Check the source code directly. If it contains something like `var eName = null`, it means that `$eName` variable doesn't have any value when you echo it, for whatever reason there is - typo, scope issues etc.

Comment: I am using ajax. If I echo in PHP I see the value in my ajax.responseText

Comment: Wait, you are returning JavaScript in an Ajax response?

Comment: all my code is in the php file directly

Comment: Felix, no i'm returning the PHP response to ajax

Comment: And the PHP response is what exactly? I don't understand how an Ajax response is related to `var eName = '<?php echo $eName; ?>';`. Please **[edit]** your question and provide more (complete) information.

Comment: I just used the ajax response to make sure the variable was not empty in my php section. I tried to make the variables global, same thing.

Comment: Can you show the code that assigns a value to this variable? Is that code before or after section with JS (i.e., `var eName = ...`)?

Comment: The code is before. It is at the top of my file

Comment: I read and followed the instruction in this post:  down vote favorite
 

This question may already have an answer here:

    How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?

This is how I got the code i'm using. Still it is still not working. This is why I am asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your edited code, I guess your variable `$eName` would be empty for the last record of the while loop.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $eName = $row["name"];
    // if the last record has the empty value for the field `name`, 
    // it will overwrite the previous value and
    // you will get `$eName` of no value out of the loop later
}
```

And moreover, make sure you are not using `<?php ?>` in the `.js` file which is not parsed by Javascript.

Comment: It is not, I get the right value after the While.